# Getting 404 Bad Request when using [FromBody] annotation in API method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm trying to send some basic POST data between an MVC and a .NET Core API.
When I post the data, I get this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route ("simple")]
public int PostSimple([FromBody] string value)
{
    return 0;
}
```

My POST code to this Controller:

```
string url = "my.api/Controller/Simple";
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json");

string data = "some data I want to post";
byte[] postArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

var response = client.UploadData(encoded, "POST", postArray);
```

This happens **only when I use `[FromBody]`**
When I remove it, I can get to the web method, but I cannot see the POSTed data.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you get a 404 [Like in your title] or a 400 [Like in the error message]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly tell your api controller to except json format (header : `Content-Type:application/json`). You then have to provide a body that follows the rule.

A raw string isn't json, that why you get back this 400 bad request.

In order to fix that, you first need to create a class to map the request json

```cs
public class MyRequest
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

then use it in your controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route ("simple")]
public int PostSimple([FromBody] MyRequest request)
{
    // access the value using request.Value
}
```

Finally, send your controller a json body

```cs
string data = "{\"value\" : \"some data I want to post\"}";
byte[] postArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

var response = client.UploadData(encoded, "POST", postArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `data` should contain a JSON string.

`var response = client.UploadData(**url**, "POST", postArray);`

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you actually send invalid data. What the server expects (from body) is this:

```
{
  "value" : "some data I want to post"
}
```

What you send is just a string, nothing else; this will result in an invalid request.
Within your POST code change your method to something like this (pseudo-coded):

```
var stringedClass = new MyClass() { value = "This is the string" };
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "url");
message.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stringedClass), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: I used a JSON string as the data, still, same result

Comment: What kind of JSON string? The method expects an object at least, but what you could do with the receiving controller is not to expect a string, but the actual object you use (like I used the MyClass as object you expect as parameter)

Answer (score 0):

It can work if you put your string in double braces.

```
""your string""
```

It's the output of serializing the string. Like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject("your string");
```

No guarantee but worked in my case.